# C++ typedef with tuple of indefinite size

Tags: c++, c++11

I am working with some C++ code that creates a set from quaternary tuples.

I would like to generalise the code so that tuples of any magnitude could be added to the set.

Is there a way of creating a typedef for a tuple of an indefinite number of elements?

For the sake of compatibility with the project that I working on I would like this to be implemented with `C++11` features. I am hoping to keep typedefs if possible so that it is consistent with the rest of the programming.

I have looked at a lot of information on variadic functions and templates, but I am still unsure how to proceed.

```
#include <set>
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>



typedef std::set<std::tuple<int, int, int, int>> QuaternarySet;
typedef std::tuple<int, int, int, int> QuaternaryTuple;

int main () {

    QuaternaryTuple x = std::make_tuple(1, 2, 3, 4);
    QuaternaryTuple y = std::make_tuple(5, 6, 7, 8);
    QuaternaryTuple z = std::make_tuple(1, 2, 3, 4);

    QuaternarySet s;

    s.insert(x);
    s.insert(y);
    s.insert(z);

    std::cout << s.size() << std::endl;
}
```

Ideally, I am looking for some code that allows me to define something like this but I am not sure what to replace the ellipses with.

```
typedef std::set<std::tuple<int ...>> IndefiniteSet;
typedef std::tuple<int ...> IndefiniteTuple;
```

That is to say, I need a run time variable size container of a single type, `int`.

Comment: If you were to use `std::vector<int>`, you'd have runtime flexibility about the size of all containers. Trying to go with a templated solution will make it way more complex and generate ton of size-dependent code for what seems like very little gain.

Comment: Tuple with indefinite number of `int` values is called `std::vector`. `std::tuple` is only useful if you need a number of objects of different types.

Comment: You can already do this, the tuple constructor is variadic? If you want runtime variability, that is not an option with `tuple`. If you need a container with static undetermined number of varying element types, make a `std::vector<std::any>`. If all the types are the same, then you don't need `tuple` or `std::any`.

Comment: Unclear what you are asking for! You need a container with compile time constant size of a single given type -> use std::array, you need a flexible run time variable size container of a single type -> use std::vector, if you need different types with compile time constant number of elements -> std::tuple. If types and size is run time variable use std::vector<std::variant>

Comment: Thanks for the prompt comments. I will clarify that I need a run time variable size container of a single type, int.

Comment: Not sure why this gets down voted. I haven't had much experience in C++ in 20 years and I am asking a question to help me understand a best practice approach to some code that I have inherited.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I need a run time variable size container of a single type, int.

If it's "run-time variable size", use `std::vector<int>`. If it's known in compile time, use `std::array<int, n>`, where `n` is your size.

`std::tuple` is meant for a few of values of possibly different types, especially in a generic context; you can think about it more as an unnamed struct than a collection.